# How to open an html page in and html div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The question might be a little misleading as I don't want to know how to open a html document in a div ,but I asked the question as I am currently facing a problem where I can't replace the html file which I have already placed in a div

I have already placed a html file in a div using ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'calender.aspx',//this is html.aspx file
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
           $(".mainBar").html(data);//mainBar is the div
        }
    });
```

this file gets placed on page load i.e document.ready function ,till here everything is fine.....my trouble starts when I want to replace the file,what I do is call a javascript function say replaceFile() on button click and write the same code to replace the file (changing the url of course)

like this

```
function replaceFile()
{
$.ajax({
        url: 'Another.aspx',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
           $(".mainBar").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

but this doesn't work,please help me out!

Comment: Assuming the `another.aspx` file exists there is no reason what you have shouldn't work. It's worth noting, what you are doing can be achieved with `$(".mainBar").load("calender.aspx");`. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no I don't see any error in the console but the div content is not changed

Comment: I'd crack open firebug and stick a breakpoint in your JS to test a) if replaceFile() is being called at all, and b) if the successs function is being called.

Comment: hmm downloading firebug right now,another weird thing I found the $ajax function is ignored when under any event like click aprt from page load

Answer (score 0):

I guess your binding is not working when you try to click on the content you loaded via ajax . So you might want to change the binding of `onclick` from

```
 $("#someButtonId").click(function(){
   replaceFile();
 });
```

to

```
 $(document).on("click","#someButtonId",function(){
   replaceFile();
 });
```

jQuery on works with current and future elements.

Comment: I tried to call function using this way here it doesn;t recognise the the buttons ID ,when I checked in the browser console I wasn't able to see the button as it a submenu in an accordian and I using the jquery accordian,it only gives span class instead of individual sub menu buttons..how can I acces the ID of that particular submenu button?

Comment: use the class selector instead of ID selection. use like `$(".yourClassName")...`

Comment: yeah I got the id ,but still can't figure out why is not loading the file

Comment: @Snedden27: check for any other script errors in the firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

with this function you will load the page into the element named result

.load( url , data, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )

```
 function replaceFile(url) 
 {
   $('#result').load(url, function() {
     alert('Load was performed.');
  });
 }

replaceFile('htmlfile.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load this in Firebug and set a break point at `$(".mainBar").html(data);` to make sure it's being called. You don't have a failure handler, so it's possible that it's actually receiving an HTTP failure code, not a success code.

I'd also look at the network traffic under the Net tab to see what the request/response looks like. That's an easy way to find out what is really going on with most AJAX calls. IE9 has similar developer tools if you want to use it and not Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: you mean mozilla brwser console?